# Android: Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError'

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, automated-tests

I have some projects with several unit tests.
When I try to execute tests in Android Studio or from terminal using `gradle clean connectedCheck` I got the following error: `Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError'`
It is reproduced on Android 5.x devices, but on 4.x no errors happen.
But if I try to run separate tests package, suite, class or certain test in Android Studio, tests are going well.

I don't understand why. I need to execute tests from terminal

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18

        testApplicationId "com.xxx.zzz.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Do anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which libs you are including. In my case, I had this problem when I included the espresso.contrib library.

You could try doing something like this though.https://stackoverflow.com/a/29423456/5280584